# Page breaks after the introduction section and \nopagebreak doesn't work

Tags: sections-paragraphs, subsection

So I want the section to start right after the introduction paragraph, but it starts a new page.
Note: I am new to this so I am not sure if I should include more than this to know what the problem is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 \noindent  
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} \textbf{text}
\end{flushleft}
\hrule
\vspace{3cm}
\begin{center}
\Huge{\textbf {text}}\\
\vspace{2mm}
\line(1,0){300}\\
\vspace{1cm}
\Large{\textbf{text}}\\
\vspace{2cm} 
\large{\textbf{Date of submission: /5/2023}}
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{flushleft}
\large{
Name:\hfill
ID: }
\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\huge{Table of Contents}}
\begin{center}
\tableofcontents
\end{center}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{4mm}}
\newpage \section*{Abstract}
\Large{text} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\vspace{1.5cm}
\section{Introduction}
\Large{text}
\vspace{1.5cm}
\section{System Modeling and Properties}
\subsection{Mathematical Modelling}
\subsection{Simulink Model}
\subsection{Open Loop transfer function}
\section{Controller Design}
\section{Simulation Results and Analysis}
\section{Conclusions}
\section{References}
\section{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: The example you've shown us doesn't have a page break after the introduction section, and doesn't have `\nopagebreak`, so we can't test it out.  You can also change the image `logo` into `example-image`, and it will compile for us.

Comment: Off-topic: Note that `\Large`, `\huge` etc. are font switches not commands with argument. So after your `\Large{text}` everything will be Large, not only `text`. And `\noindent` before `\begin{flushleft}` also does not make sense.

Comment: @Teepeemm I edited the image. I found that the error doesn't appear here but for the actual text I have, it appears that half the page is empty after the paragraph is over and it starts the new section on a new page. When I tried to make the font smaller, it worked fine, so what if I want it to be in the same size I used here?

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. @cabohah